# EJB 2.0 VS EJB 3.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

In EJB 2.0 we have Home interface, and Component interface. But in EJB 3.0 we don't have those interfaces(instead we have annotations). My doubt is, if we don't have those interface, then who is doing their job in EJB 3.0, and how the implementation and working (calling and callee) procedure changed??

Comment: The EJB Container does the injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EJB 3 you don't need the home interface anymore, as the container is directly injecting the bean when you use the `@EJB` annotation

```
@EJB
MyLocalInterface bean1;

@EJB
OtherRemoteInterface bean2;

String foo = bean1.doSomething();
String bar = bean2.soSomethingElse();
```

Comment: Do we have the stub and skeleton in EJB 3.0??